# Microsoft SQL DatabaseLink connection using Windows Authentication

Tags: windows, databaselink, sql

For those who use *Mathematica* with databases in companies, a common way to securely connect to those is using Windows Authentication (detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905171%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)).

*Mathematica* doesn't seem to support this authentication method. How can you connect to a database securely using Windows authentication?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After much digging, I found [this](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2012/Apr/msg00377.html) MathGroup archive detailing how to get *Mathematica* working with SQL servers protected by Windows authentication.

It's repeated here mainly for posterity's sake.

1. Download the jTDS files from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/
2. Unzip and locate the ntlmauth.dll file in the appropriate folder (x64, x86, IA64).
3. Copy this file to `$InstallationDirectory` under SystemFiles>Java>(appropriate Windows folder)>bin
4. Restart *Mathematica*.

Let's hope Wolfram decides to include this in the next version.

**Update for V10**

Now in V10 jTDS 1.3.1 is the standard. No need to manual upgrade.

Comment: Wow!.. this really works. I just implemented it in version 9. Tks

Comment: @Murta, I really hoped they implemented it in v9. It's crucial to a lot of us in enterprises.

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is no. Now I have another challenge that is similar to your post [in this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15973/microsoft-sql-databaselink-connection-using-windows-authentication-from-mac).

Comment: I have a 32-bit operating system. When I downloaded the jTDS file and unzipped it I saw two folders, one called x64 and one called x86 both containing the ntlmauth.dll file. There was no folder for x32. Which version of this file should I use? Also, when I went to my Mathematica\...\Java folder there are two sub-folders, one called "Windows" and one called "Windows-x86-64". Both of these folders have a "bin" sub-folder. Which of these is the correct folder to use?

Comment: @LaraJordan, x86 is 32bit. Grab the .dll from that folder and place it under Java>Windows not Windows-x86-64...

Comment: Another option is to use ODBC. Just configure a named connection in the Windows ODBC Control panel and use DatabaseExplorer to puck this up. Works always for me.

Comment: @kale What do you actually mean by "Now in V10 jTDS 1.3.1 is the standard. No need to manual upgrade." You don't have to copy the ntlmauth.dll file? I don't see it in my folders.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I'm almost positive they included ntlmauth.dll in the v10 releases. I connect to SQL servers all the time with it now using Windows authentication. It's not in the folder I mention in my answer, but I *think* it's somewhere else (I'll look tomorrow). If, by chance, you're trying to make a SQL connection in v11, it's quite broken right now because Java no longer includes the needed jTDS hooks. (I have a bug report in with WRI)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries In v11 on MacOS, this file is located in /Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Links/DatabaseLink/Java/Libraries/Windows-x86-64 by default (I'm guessing that's where it is on the PC side)

Comment: @kale I moved to v11 indeed (see my question of today). Good that you've been working on this already. Did you find a workaround for the time being?