# OpenSQLConnection SSPI Library Not Loaded

Tags: databaselink, sql, security

I am attempting to open a connection to SQL Server with Windows Authentication (SSPI) using `OpenSQLConnection` and `JDBC`.

```
dbConn = OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["Microsoft SQL Server(jTDS)", "servername/dbname"]]
```

However, I am getting the following error from this.

```
JDBC::error: I/O Error: SSO Failed: Native SSPI library not loaded. Check the java.library.path system property. >>
```

*How do I load the "Native SSPI" library so that this connection can be opened?*

I need to use integrated security so cannot pass in the username/password combo. The [jTDS feature matrix](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/features.html) says that it supports Window Authentication and Mma appears to be using the latest version of the driver (1.3.1).

```
JDBCDrivers["Microsoft SQL Server(jTDS)"]
(*
JDBCDriver["Name" -> "Microsoft SQL Server(jTDS)", 
 "Driver" -> "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver", 
 "Protocol" -> "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://", "Version" -> 3., 
 "Description" -> 
  "Microsoft SQL Server using jTDS - Version 1.3.1 - This supports \
   Microsoft SQL Server 6.5, 7, 2000, 2005, 2008, and 2012.", 
 "Location" -> 
  "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
   Research\\Mathematica\\10.0\\SystemFiles\\Links\\DatabaseLink\\\
   DatabaseResources\\sqlserverjtds.m"]
*)
```

Comment: Have you been through this post in detail? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10312/microsoft-sql-databaselink-connection-using-windows-authentication?rq=1

Comment: Thanks @GordonCoale .  That did the trick.  If it is just a matter of including an open source DLL in the install I wonder why Wolfram doesn't include it?

Comment: I tend to agree.  It took me 2 days to get the oracle jdbc driver working.

Comment: Admins, think you can merge this question with http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10312/microsoft-sql-databaselink-connection-using-windows-authentication?rq=1  as it is solved by the process in that answer.