# Mathematica 10.3 on Windows 10 Home Premium Connection to SQL Server 2016

Tags: databaselink, sql, databases

Having installed sql server 2016 evaluation copy.

I have setup a sample database using sql server management studio.

Typed the following in mathematica

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"];

JDBCDrivers["Microsoft SQL Server(jTDS)"];
```

No error in the output of the two commands. MS SQL Server is using windows authentication for login.

```
OpenSQLConnection[
 JDBC["Microsoft SQL Server (jTDS)", "server/database"], 
 "Username" -> "user", "Password" -> "password"]
```

gives the following error

```
JDBC::classnotfound: Microsoft SQL Server (jTDS) >>
$Failed
```

Please help i am a new to this. Just learned sql server and now want to integrate it into mathematica.

Also are there any tutorial on `DatabaseLink` package of mathematica

After following the instruction on the other post i still get the same error

```
JDBC::classnotfound: Microsoft SQL Server (jTDS) >>
$Failed
```

Also for windows authentication should i just use the following then right?

```
OpenSQLConnection[
 JDBC["Microsoft SQL Server (jTDS)", "server/database"]]
```

The server name is `DESKTOP-4SGK8AQ` and database name is `LearningSQL` so i am using the following code

```
OpenSQLConnection[
 JDBC["Microsoft SQL Server (jTDS)", "DESKTOP-4SGK8AQ/LearningSQL"]]
```

Everything works now `"Microsoft SQL Server (jTDS)"` should be corrected to `"Microsoft SQL Server(jTDS)"`. My mistake

Comment: With Windows Authentication you need to download a jTDS dll file. [Read this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10312/). Also, note that you should not set the _Username_ and _Password_ in the connection when using Windows Authentication.

Comment: Followed the instruction on the post still the same error:
JDBC::classnotfound: Microsoft SQL Server (jTDS) >>
$Failed

Comment: There is a 32bit and a 64bit version of the file. You have to put the right version in the correct Java directory. You should check it works with 2014 as well. In case it is a bug with Mathematica and 2016. You can get SQL Server Express 2014 is free.

Comment: Ok i am installing the 2014 version of sql server and will try again. Are you sure it works with 2014 right?

Comment: Yes. I use it with 2014 Express at home and 2014 at work.

Comment: Thank you Edmund, is it possible can you tell me the exact commands you use to connect to a database kept on your local machine on windows with windows authentication. That would make life easier. Also is there any setting in the management studio that i have to do before the connection?

Comment: Copying the ntlmauth.dll file from x64\SSO to C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.3\SystemFiles\Java\Windows-x86-64\bin

and from x86\SSO to C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.3\SystemFiles\Java\Windows\bin

does nothing. Does it need to be placed someplace else?

Also now i am running SQL Server 2014 now

Comment: I made a chat and put some comments on setup there. `dbConn = OpenSQLConnection[
  JDBC["Microsoft SQL Server(jTDS)", "LOCALHOST"], 
  "Instance" -> "SQLEXPRESS", "DatabaseName" -> "Testing"]`